# html5 checkbox validation tooltip issued behavior

Tags: html, angular, validation

during validation of the checkbox in chrome browser, when I click submit of the form,
tooltip/bubble message is not showned right away but after moving mouse on checkbox or leaving sumbit button...

```html
<form ... onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
...
<p><input type="checkbox" required name="terms"> I accept the <u>Terms and Conditions</u></p>
<p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

[jsfiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/ke17a9c6/)

[example number 2 here](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-checkbox-required/)

Can someone explain me what its happening, how to solve it?
On opera its tottally fine for example...

Thanks

Comment: Please add working links.

Comment: Sorry. Here you go.

Comment: Please also implement the complete code used in the example number 2 you posted. You did not include the javascript, and please exclude the '...' as they are only placeholders. Also this does not have much to do with angular. If you are using Angular I would suggest reading up on Angular form validation: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the example `...` dots, and provide `function checkForm(form)` in between `<script></script>` tags that actually runs the javascript code to check it.

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gejsf0x6/